# facebook sharing showing wrong image and html url

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am using add this to share content from my site www.halisi-kenya.com but it is posting the wrong image thumnails any one to help.Then secondly my url is showing funny characters at the end  http://www.halisi-kenya.com/entry.php?id=55#.UoIPEnD0CyY anyone to help

```
<?php
      include('admin/db_connections/aardb_conn.php');
      $query = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE autoid=".$_GET['id'];
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

   $title = $row['title'];
   $intro = $row['intro'];
   $date = $row['timestamp'];
   $user = $row['userid'];
   $content = $row['body'];
   $image1 = $row['image'];
   $autoid = $row['autoid'];
   $queryi = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE autoid=".$row['userid'];
   $resulti = mysql_query($queryi) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
   $rowi = mysql_fetch_array($resulti, MYSQL_ASSOC);
   $fname = $rowi['fname'];
   $lname = $rowi['lname'];
   $author=$fname." ".$lname;
      ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="title" content="Halisi Kenya - It's a lifestyle">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Halisi kenya,<?php echo $title; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php   $Name = strip_tags($content);
 echo $Name;?>">
<meta name="author" content="Billy Ochieng">
<meta name="copyright" content="Halisi Kenya">
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="info@halisi-kenya.com">

    <!-- Custom Styles Styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Support for HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Enable media queries on older browsers -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45485412-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>   
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=538741216211393";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="container">

<header id="breadcrumb">
<ul class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-light breadcrumb-divider-middot">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><?php echo $title; ?></li>
</ul>                   
</header>

<aside class="two-col">
<header class="title2 big-title col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
</header>

<article class="blog-wrap content col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="blogimg">
<img class="media-object" alt="" src="admin/<?php echo $image1; ?>">
</div>
<p><strong class="text-success"><?php echo $intro; ?></strong></p>
<p> <?php echo $content; ?></p>
<div class="post-tags">
<?php echo $date;?>
</div> 

<section class="comments">
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-508e4b7b0cb342b4"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->

</section>
<div class="post-author">
<h3>By <a href="#"><strong><?php echo $author;?> </strong></a></h3>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</article>

<section class="comments">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.halisi-kenya.com/entry.php?id=<?php echo $autoid;?>" data-numposts="5" width="600"></div>
</section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define meta og tag in the header part.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "http://halisikenya.com/admin/".$row['image'];?>">

<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOURWEBSITE.com/YOURIMAGE.png">
```

each image should be in aspect ratio of 1.91:1, min 600px X 315px or max 1200px X 630px

after that you need to debug each url of your blog in FB debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.halisi-kenya.com%2Fentry.php%3Fid%3D55%23.UoIUx_lQHAN

if there is  on your site then you will see in debugger only one image which you specify in og tag.

[image: Please see below debugger screen shot]

Comment: the images are dynamic being fetched from the database so cant place the exact name coz all the pages link to this page

Comment: you can use <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "http://www.halisi-kenya.com/". $row['image']?>">

Comment: am getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/content/80/11429180/html/halisi/entry.php on line 26

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "http://halisi-kenya.com/". $row['image'];?>">

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="http://halisi-kenya.com/admin/ads/a6c1a6f11694707646f581173a0d7142.jpg"> your code should generate dynamic code like this

Comment: you have to generate dynamic image - for content. image url should be full URL not relative so it should be string of website+imagepath

Comment: I have copy the link and pasted in between my head tags n it gave me an error

Comment: like this <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo "halisi-kenya.com/admin/ads/.$row['image']?>;"> –